# urllib2.ProxyHandler with HTTPS regression when upgrading from python-2.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-2.7, urllib2

When upgrading from python-2.5 to python-2.7, the following code was broken:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2
>>> from django.conf import settings

>>> settings.AUTH_URL
'https://auth.example.net/auth/'
>>> settings.HTTP_PROXY
{'http': 'http://proxy.example.net', 'https': 'https://proxy.example.net'}
>>> cred = urllib.urlencode({'username': 'someuser', 'password': 'somepasswd'})

>>> urllib2.urlopen(settings.AUTH_URL, data=cred).read()
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><auth><username value="someuser">true</username><password>true</password></auth>'

>>> urllib2.build_opener().open(settings.AUTH_URL, data=cred).read()
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><auth><username value="someuser">true</username><password>true</password></auth>'

>>> urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler(settings.HTTP_PROXY)).open(settings.AUTH_URL, data=cred).read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler(settings.HTTP_PROXY))
>>> opener
<urllib2.OpenerDirector instance at 0x1bc39d40>
>>> opener.__dict__
{'addheaders': [('User-agent', 'Python-urllib/2.7')],
 'handle_error': {'http': {301: [<urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7a0>],
                       302: [<urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7a0>],
                       303: [<urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7a0>],
                       307: [<urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7a0>],
                       'default': [<urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7e8>]}},
 'handle_open': {'file': [<urllib2.FileHandler instance at 0x1bc43098>],
             'ftp': [<urllib2.FTPHandler instance at 0x1bc3ffc8>],
             'http': [<urllib2.ProxyHandler instance at 0x1bfa0638>,
                      <urllib2.HTTPHandler instance at 0x1bc3f758>],
             'https': [<urllib2.ProxyHandler instance at 0x1bfa0638>,
                       <urllib2.HTTPSHandler instance at 0x1bc43200>],
             'unknown': [<urllib2.UnknownHandler instance at 0x1bc3f830>]},
 'handlers': [<urllib2.ProxyHandler instance at 0x1bfa0638>,
          <urllib2.UnknownHandler instance at 0x1bc3f830>,
          <urllib2.HTTPHandler instance at 0x1bc3f758>,
          <urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7e8>,
          <urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler instance at 0x1bc3f7a0>,
          <urllib2.FTPHandler instance at 0x1bc3ffc8>,
          <urllib2.FileHandler instance at 0x1bc43098>,
          <urllib2.HTTPSHandler instance at 0x1bc43200>,
          <urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor instance at 0x1bc43128>],
 'process_request': {'http': [<urllib2.HTTPHandler instance at 0x1bc3f758>],
                 'https': [<urllib2.HTTPSHandler instance at 0x1bc43200>]},
 'process_response': {'http': [<urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor instance at 0x1bc43128>],
                  'https': [<urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor instance at 0x1bc43128>]}}
>>> sock = opener.open(settings.AUTH_URL, data=cred)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

This last expression still works on python-2.5 but does not work on 2.7 on the same physical machine with the same proxy and url settings. Any idea why?

Comment: Trying to debug a 105-character line with at least 4 function calls in it is generally not a pleasant thing to do, but if you break it down into `ph = urllib2.ProxyHandler(settings.HTTP_PROXY)`, then `opener = urllib2.build_opener(ph)`, then `f = opener.open(settings.AUTH_URL, data=cred)`, then `f.read()` it gets a lot easier. Yes, it's possible to guess that the `open` method is problem from the traceback, but it would be a lot easier to debug if we didn't have to guess—plus, you can compare what the intermediate objects look like in 2.5 vs. 2.7, or show them to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the 'https' key from settings.HTTP_PROXY but not sure why. The URL is still HTTPS.